# Macro to read cells in one sheet and then search for match in another sheet and add date to column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to write an excel macro that will go down a column of text and then search for each item in the column in another spreadsheet in the same workbook. When the value is found it should put todays date in a specific column e.g. column H. I have found some code that will do the first part and another piece of code that will do the second part. I just haven't got the knowledge of coding to put the two together and make it work. The two pieces of code are shown below.

```
Sub From_sheet_make_array()

  Dim myarray As Variant
  Dim cells As Range
  Dim cl



      myarray = Range("a1:a10").Value

      Set cells = Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).cells

      Set cl = cells.cells(1)
      Do
      If IsError(Application.Match(cl.Value, myarray, False)) Then
      Exit Sub
      Else:
            i = i + 1
      'This shows each item in column in messagebox
      'Need to pass this value to other code somehow
            MsgBox (cl.Value)

     End If
```

Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
     Loop While Not IsEmpty(cl.Value)
   End Sub

```
Sub Searchlist()

Dim c As Range
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
' This will search for whatever is in ""
' Somehow need to get cl.Value (myarray) in here
    Set c = .Columns("A").Find(What:="text", _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
             c.Offset(0, 8).Value = Date
End With
Exit Sub
```

End Sub

If anyone can stitch them together or point me in the right direction of how to go about it would really help me out. I could be way off as I am very new to this. Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you're in a process of checking if you have the entry for today in another worksheet and if you do, you put a date-stamp in your current worksheet.
Try this: (let me know if it works!)

```
Sub DateStampIfFound()
Dim cell As Range
Dim temp As Range
For Each cell In Sheets("worksheet_containing_search_criteria").UsedRange.Columns("Specify_the_column").Cells
    'so you dont search for blanks and skipping header row
    If cell <> "" and cell.row<>1 Then
        Set temp = Sheets("worksheet_where_you_want_the_find_to_happen").Columns("Specify_the_column").Find(What:=cell.Value, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        'if found
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then
            'if the search_criteria is in the same sheet
            cell.Offset(0, number_of_columns_offset_from_cell) = Date
        End If
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Derek. Thanks for your reply. When I run the macro I get a Run-time error '13' Type mismatch On the line - If cell <> "". If I comment out this line then the macro runs ok. However it date-stamps the sheet containing the search criteria (as you said in your comment). How do I get the date-stamp in the sheet where I want the find to happen?

Comment: hi, my mistake there I forgot to put ".Cells" after "Columns("Specify_the_column")" in the for line. I've updated my code, please give it another try.

Comment: if you want the date stamp next to the found cell, instead of 
"cell.Offset(0, number_of_columns_offset_from_cell) = Date" you can try "temp.offset(...)"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this Derek. It works perfectly now. Much appreciated.